# symfony : There are no commands defined in the "generate" namespace

Tags: php, symfony

I want to create a bundle in symfony with this commande :

```
php bin/console generate:bundle
```

and i got this [error](https://user.oc-static.com/upload/2019/10/18/15713591495618_Capture.PNG) :

```
There are no commands defined in the "generate" namespace.



You may be looking for a command provided by the "SensioGeneratorBundle" which is currently not installed. Try running "composer require sensio/generator-bundle".
```

any solution for this problem?

thank you in advance

Comment: Which version of Symfony? If flex or >= 4.x you may be looking for the [`symfony/maker-bundle`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html) In 3.x  Is the [`sensio/generator-bundle`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/index.html) installed and loaded in your AppKernel dev environment? Lastly make sure you manually delete your Symfony cache, `/var/cache/*`

Answer (score 1):

Just run this command:

```
composer require sensio/generator-bundle
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command if you have new symfony version

```
composer require symfony/maker-bundle --dev
```

otherwise use this command

```
composer require sensio/generator-bundle
```